# Android Studio automatically converting some Class's name. How to restrict this?

Tags: java, android, linux, windows, android-studio

I was using Android Studio in **Linux** where there was a Class named **WorkSpace.java** in my project. Now I have migrated to a **Windows** system with Android Studio 4.2.1 and imported my project. But there were error while building the project because the class **WorkSpace.java is automatically renamed to Workspace.java** but all references to this class was same, ex.

`private WorkSpace workspace;`

So, I have to manually convert WorkSpace to Workspace to solve all errors. The main problem is I have lots of projects with same class name and hundreds of uses and all are pushed to GIT, so it is very tedious job to change in every project. Is there any solution to keep WorkSpace.java as it is?

Comment: If the transfer from Linux to UNIX blew something, but you are using GIT, why can't you just do a `git reset`?